# Два Navigation Drawer в Android

Tags: java, android

В приложения хочу сделать два Navigation Drawer, как в приложении Stack Exchange. Есть ли где нибудь примеры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто поместите в `DrawerLayout` 3 вьюхи:

1. Для контента
2. Для левого меню с `android:gravity="start"`
3. Для правого меню с `android:gravity="end"`

Comment: чет я не понял можете примером?

Comment: Долго набирать. Я не знаю как ещё проще. Надо DrawerLayout и в нём 3 любых других вьюхи. Те, у коих будут  gravity проставлены - будут работать как меню слева и справа

Comment: понял все элементарно оказалось

Comment: большое спасибо